# vim uses a different rc file for 2 different files in the same folder. How come?

Tags: vim

I have 2 text files: file1.txt and fil2.txt in my home directory.
I am using /usr/bin/vim to open both of them.
When looking to find which is the last script used to set the attributes (e.g. :verbose set textwidth?) they yield different results. How come ? Where is that info stored ?

vim file1.txt

```
:verbose set textwidth?
  textwidth=78
        Last set from /etc/vimrc
```

vim file2.txt

```
:verbose set textwidth?
  textwidth=120
        Last set from ~/.exrc
```

Just to add to the puzzle or maybe help with getting the answer: if I copy file2.txt to a new file (i.e. file3.txt) then the new file gets "Last set from /etc/vimrc"):

```
cp file2.txt file3.txt
vim file3.txt
:verbose set textwidth?
  textwidth=78
        Last set from /etc/vimrc
```

Here is a more info on the new file3.txt I just created: The Xterm where I created the new file3.txt shows "Last set from /etc/vimrc" on the other hand if I go into another Xterm (let's call it Xterm2) I had opened a while ago and check on the file3.txt it shows "Last set from ~/.exrc". So the answer has to be related to the Xterm env settings as well.
To summarize:

```
Xterm file2.txt -> ~/.exrc
Xterm file3.txt -> /etc/vimrc
Xterm2 file2.txt -> ~/.exrc
Xterm2 file3.txt -> ~/.exrc
```

Comment: better ask that question here http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is in `~/.exrc`?

Comment: I think it would be better to show the content of your `.vimrc` used by your vim and `.exrc` because the answer is there and say which files you have sourced.

Comment: Can you mention the value of `$VIM` ? or show directly your default `vimrc ` ?

Comment: Here are some answers:
---
cat .exrc
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set autoindent
set backup
set hardtabs=4
set expandtab
set backupext=.bak
verbose set textwidth=120
"use gqG to reformat the entire document or gq{ to reminder of the file
"set wrapmargin=2
"set gfn=Monospace\ 10
set gfn=Monospace\ 9
":colors default
...
I do not have a .vimrc in my home directory only .exrc. That is on propose to share it with vanila vi
---
echo $VIM is empty

Comment: Then vim is using `"$HOME/.exrc"` as default one.

Comment: Not always. As you can see some more details I have captured in question body sometimes vim uses /etc/vimrc. The focus of the question is to find why and have a better control on how vim uses rc files.

Answer (score 0):

> Where is that info stored ?

For each option of `set` command (*set [option]*) vim is holding characteristics related to each one.

One of these characteristics, is the id of the script in which the last set was made.

So Vim does not hold that infomation in any file, it writes them directly on the screen.

If you have set the `verbosefile` option vim will **copy** those messages shown by `verbose` **command** according to the verboselevel in a file.

> When looking to find which is the last script used to set the
>   attributes (e.g. :verbose set textwidth?) they yield different
>   results. How come ?

You need to check your `/etc/vimrc`, `~/.exrc`, plugins and sourced files to know the order that was made to set `textwidth` option so you can understand why it is the last script setting it.

Comment: Why would the plugins order be different for 2 text files located in the same folder (i.e. home directory) ?

Comment: 2 files have 2 different names, 2 different contents maybe, 2 different locations ....so it could be one plugin is setting one file and not the other. I have just mentioned it so you understand and follow the sequence of setting the option but what is sure is that the two files mentioned in your question are the last ones which had set textwidth.

Answer (score 0):

```
.exrc is the configuration file for vi, 
.vimrc is the config file for vim
```

So, file1.txt was edited and saved in vim; file2.txt was edited and saved in vi. 
(Note: vim will use .vimrc configuration file, but if it doesn't exist, it will resort to .exrc.)

`textwidth=xxx` is a configuration that you can put in the .vimrc or .exrc config file.

Comment: If I use vim to edit and save file2.txt next time when I open it with vim I get the same "Last set from ~/.exrc".

Comment: Do you or your shell environment have access to .vimrc, or can you only find the .exrc?

Comment: I do not have a .vimrc in my home directory. I only keep ~/.exrc with the intent to use it for both vim and vanilla vi.

Comment: Use :scriptnames, and compare opening these two files. :scriptnames will show you the order sourced files.

Comment: I know about :scrptnames but what is important here is the last one executed. The question still stands - why 2 files in the same directory in the same Xterm show a different last script executed ?

Comment: That's exactly the claim I wish to validate by checking :scriptnames. Can you confirm that when you open file1.txt and check :scriptnames it has sourced etc/vimrc and not .exrc? likewise, can you confirm that file2.txt has sourced etc/vimrc and then .exrc? Knowing this definitively will help answer your question.

Comment: :scriptnames shows in the 1st line exactly what :verbose set textwidth? shows. For file1.txt it shows /etc/vimrc in the 1st line.

Comment: ...and file2.txt?

Comment: 1: /home/$USER/.exrc (I just replaced my real userid with $USER).

Comment: Ok, interesting.  So, we have to look for corner cases:  Confirm that you don't have any environmental settings in your Xterm that are affecting this behavior: check each of these $EXINT, $VIMINT, $VIM, $VIMRUNTIME, or $MYVIMRC. (see :help initialization for details)